# Why does my python Pandas Gooey interface not execute the Pandas commands?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and pandas in general. I managed to create a simple merge script, now i want to carry that script over to a GUI interface using Gooey.

Example:

I have two files that are made up of this type of data.

One csv contains 3 columns named [A, B, C]

The second csv contains [A, D, E]

I want to merge this files such as they become [A, B, C, D, E]

If I run this part of the code by itself it works:

```
          load1 = pd.read_csv("*.csv")
          load2 = pd.read_csv("*.csv")
          merged = load2.merge(load1, on='A',how='right')
          merged.to_csv("itworks.csv", index=False)
```

---

However when I try to do it in Gooey, it executes and completes but it appears it never executes what is in def merge().

Question: Why is the merge function not executing?

```
 from __future__ import print_function
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import glob
    import os
    import json
    from argparse import ArgumentParser
    from gooey import Gooey, GooeyParser
    import argparse

    @Gooey

    def main():
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser = GooeyParser(description='Example')
        parser.add_argument(
            'load1',
            action='store',
            help='Choose carefully',
            widget='FileChooser',

            )    
        parser.add_argument(
            'load2',
            action='store',
            help='Choose carefully',
            widget='FileChooser',
            )

        args = parser.parse_args()

        return args

    def merge(load1, load2):

      load1 = pd.read_csv("*.csv")
      load2 = pd.read_csv("*.csv")
      merged = load2.merge(load1, on='A',how='right')
      merged.to_csv("itworks.csv", index=False)

      return merge

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        conf = main()
```

Comment: Never used Gooey. But code defined in a function block will not run unless that function is actually called

Comment: I am not sure that you want to have merge returned in the `merge` function

Comment: @roganjosh so to call it I can just call merge () at the end of the code. If that is the correct way of calling it. I get this error "merge() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'load1' and 'load2"

Comment: I'm not sure your code can throw that error. You haven't shown how `merge()` is called, but it seems you're not passing any arguments to it. You need to call it and pass it 2 things that represent what you want `load1` and `load2` to be regarded as inside that function.

Comment: @roganjosh I want to pass conf.load1 and conf.load2 to the merge function. The 2 csvs are loading into conf1 and 2 respectively. How can I do that?